# When you have an index is using `min` and `max` faster than `$gte` and `$lt`? Why?

Tags: mongodb

Sorry for the basic question, I'm new to MongoDB.

Suppose you have a collection called "students" with an index on a field called "grade".  Which of these would be faster?

`db.students.find({"grade": {$gte: 50}, "grade": {$lt: 90}})`

`db.students.find().min("grade": 50).max("grade": 90)`

Other than the ability to provide a `hint` to the second option, is there and advantage to the second option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query will be faster because it allows for bounding on the index. This is best seen when using [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/).

For example:

```
db.stack.find({ "grade" : { "$lt" : 90, "$gt" : 50 } }).explain()

{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "test.stack",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [
                {
                    "grade" : {
                        "$lt" : 90
                    }
                },
                {
                    "grade" : {
                        "$gt" : 50
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "grade" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "grade_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "grade" : [ ]
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "grade" : [
                        "(50.0, 90.0)"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
```

The `indexBounds` field above shows that the query is only scanning a subset of the index, specifically the keys between 50 and 90.

In comparison, the other form of the query scans the range of index and then parses the resulting cursor to perform the `min` and `max` functions:

```
db.stack.find().min({ "grade" : 50 }).max({"grade" : 90 }).explain()
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "test.stack",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {

        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "grade" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "grade_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "grade" : [ ]
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {

                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
```

Note how `indexBounds` above is empty.

Make sense?

**One other important note**: the query listed in your question will not work as expected, as it will only apply the `$lte : 90` filter in its current form.

Queries that apply multiple filters on a single field will need to use the [$and operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) to perform a logical `AND` across the multiple conditions. In my examples above, I instead combined the multiple filters into a single condition:

```
{ "grade" : { "$lt" : 90, "$gt" : 50 } }
```

This should be the same as:

```
{ 
  "$and" : [ 
    { grade : { "$gt" : 50 } }, 
    { grade: { "$lt" : 90 } } 
  ] 
}
```